# Is there a way to get rid of caching in VS Code notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to programatically get rid of caching in python? I have the following code in a cell in python notebook in VSCode. After i run this, i return True and have 2 as printed.

```
def oracle():
    print(2)

def function():
    oracle()
    return True

function()
```

Now if i then change this code and run the cell again with the following changes:

```
def oracle():
    print(2)

def function():
    oracle1()
    return True

function()
```

When I run the new changes, i still get True returned and 2 is printed. I am thinking this is because the notebook is caching things. Is there a way to programatically get rid of caching?

Comment: I don't see how this code runs at all, because `oracle1()` is not defined...

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I get `NameError: name 'oracle1' is not defined`. Try reproducing it for yourself in a new notebook. If you still don't get the error, try in a new environment.

Comment: It worked for me on first script. Using Python 3.12.2. It printed 2

Comment: Typo error in second script.  Should be `oracle` instead of `oracle1`

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue as well. But to clear jupyter’s cache, I can give you some suggestion:

You could restart your jupyter kernel by clicking `Restart` in top menu.

[image]

If you want to do this automatically in your code, you can use `reset` command. This will clear all definitions but will not restart the kernel. You can add `%reset -f` at the top of your code cell, such as:

```
%reset -f
def oracle():
    print(2)

def function():
    oracle1()
    return True

function()
```